# Flutter app doesn't have internet permission in APK file

Tags: flutter, dart

My APK build file in flutter doesn't have internet permission.
I already did this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.Supplier_app">
    <!-- Flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a very general issue faced by flutter beginners.

In android, each required permission is specified in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

For native coding there is only one file inside `app/src/main`. For flutter, there are not one but 3 of these.

1. `app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml` - for debug mode
2. `app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`- for app distribution in release mode
3. `app/src/profile/AndroidManifest.xml` - for running app in profile mode

The internet permission is provided by default in the `debug` mode. So, internet works without doing anything.

**All the permissions required for app distribution must be specified in** `app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`. *For testing purpose, the permissions are specified in other files mentioned.*

Answer (score 0):

Please check the mode of the app in which you have permission. It should be in main/AndroidManifest.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to edit the AndroidManifest.xml that is located inside the "debug" directory. The AndroidManifest.xml you are looking for is located in the **app\src\main** path.