# Firestore Release APK Doesn't Read and write But Storage Works Flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am using firestore and storage for my flutter android and ios app. On debug mode everything is fine, reading and writing to firestore and storage works. But when turning to release mode on android firestore reading and writing dont work. What could be the case?
I could not finish my project for a long time. Your help is really appreciated.

When running project by typing following command, no error occurs.

```
flutter run --release
```

Build apk with following command :

```
flutter build apk --release
```

Comment: does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63439914

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have seen the repository but not be able try yet. It uploads image and pdf, so it uses internet. Could it be still the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your Android Apps Configuration in Firebase Console, under General Tab, you have to add SHA fingerprint for your app's release version.

You can find your SHA fingerprint certificate for your released app under Setup, App Integrity from your left menu in your Play Console.

It will works with either your SHA-1 or SHA-256 fingerprint certificate.

**EDIT** Above will works if you publish your release app through Google Play signing.

If you distribute your release app by yourself, you can check the SHA-1 fingerprint certificate from your project's [gradle signing report](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth#using_gradles_signing_report). In there, you can find it for the Variant : Release

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how the app upload photos and pdf without fingerprint certificate? Do you have any information about it?

Comment: Also I build the release apk not for publishing. I will only share with client

Comment: I don't have any idea. Maybe Firebase Storage doesn't need it. And I think my answer still applies, because fingerprint certificate is a must, and for release version, is different from debug version, you can easily find it in your play console.

Comment: I added sha 256 and sha 1 fingerprint certificates but didnt work. It writes data to storage but dont write firestore

Comment: Ah, I missed that you're not publishing the release app to Google Play. So, you can check the SHA-1 from your project's [gradle signing report](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth#using_gradles_signing_report). In there, you can find it for the Variant : Release

Comment: Yes I have done it. Sha keys added to firebase settings. Dont work unfortunatelly. Do I need to download google-services.json  again? I get following issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68008873/flutter-release-app-firestore-fatal-exception